# Run-time Error 9 for Workbooks.Activate

Tags: vba, excel

I am having the error in Visual Basic when I try to use the function

```
Workbooks("C:\Documents and Settings\Nega\test.xls").Activate
```

The error says that:

> Error **9** in run time error: 
>   **Subscript out of range**.

I saw a lot of post about extension, but my file exists and the extension is correct.

It is may problems of privileges? In that case how can I add privileges in VBA for this directory?

Note: If I do **Workbooks("test.xls").Activate** it works (Ofc, with the file into the project). So for this I think it is about privileges.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Workbooks("test.xls").Activate. You say it is working, so why not just use it?

Comment: @ExcelDevelopers But it would only works if this file is already open and I suppose Nega wants to open it if it's closed. Is it right, Nega?

Comment: Because I need to do out of the folder project..

Yes Mielk I want to open it, and i do with  Workboos(path).Open and this works.

But when I try to use Workbooks.Activate i have the runtime error

Comment: In that case you have to open it before you can activate it. Workbooks.Open FileName:=YourFullPathString

Comment: I do, but having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

A few details about your question and the reasons it doesn't work:

"Workbooks" is a collection of files currently open in Excel

- your file exists on disk, but if is not open it doesn't exist in Workbooks collection, so the first step is to open it (as suggested)
- once the file is open Excel adds it to Workbooks collection. You can highlight the word "Workbooks" in VBA and add it to the Watches window to see all its items (files) and each item's properties
- you have access to the items in the collection by their .Name

  - the name doesn't include the path, only Name.ext
- if the file is not saved yet, the name doesn't contain the extension

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub wbActivate()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    MsgBox Workbooks.Count  'currently open files count: 1
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open("C:\test.xls")
    MsgBox Workbooks.Count  'currently open files count: 2

    wb.Activate                     'the file we just opened
    Workbooks("test.xls").Activate  'the file we just opened

    Workbooks("book1").Activate     'initial file (unsaved yet)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Few things need to be fixed here:

- You miss colon in the filepath. It should be **C:\Documents and Settings\Nega\test.xls**.
- You have a typo in the name of the function - it should be `Workbooks`.
- You can't activate a file unless it is open, so first you needs to ensure that it is already open. You can do it with this command:

  ```
  Call Workbooks.Open("C:\Documents and Settings\Nega\test.xls").Activate
  ```

Comment: Well, i forgot to put the colon in the filepath here, but not in the code. I edit the post, Sorry for this.

I have it Open but didnt works too,

Answer (score 0):

you can't use path names in the workbooks.activate 
When/because the Excelfile is already open it only needs the filename WITHOUT the path.
So 
Workbooks("C:\MN\DoubleClick.xlsx").Activate will give the error
while
Workbooks("Double click worklist BTN.xlsx").Activate wil work perfectly